# Using Angular App on a different local host. Now I get this error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
Error: Arguments array must have arguments.
    at injectArgs (core.js:1382)
    at core.js:1461
    at _callFactory (core.js:8223)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:8181)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8156)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:8849)
    at inject (core.js:1373)
    at injectArgs (core.js:1404)
    at core.js:1461
    at _callFactory (core.js:8223)
```

I'm really not to sure why I'm getting this error. I'm trying to use my app at different house. I changed the IP address for any PHP calls to the server. Yet, the app doesn't work and  I receive the above error. I can connect to the server without any problems.

Comment: probably a corrupted `node_modules`. Remove the folder `node_modules` and `npm install` again.

Comment: Then I'd have to install all previous node_modules.. right?

Comment: it could be a base-href problem. Do you have the same context-root for the page on the different hosts?

Comment: @mark I'm not to sure what you mean?

Comment: when do you get this problem? by build or by start?

Comment: On start , after ng serve --open

Comment: ok, then ignore my comment :)

Comment: @JD333 I have the same issue at the moment. Have you found a solution?

Comment: hah, it annoyed me.

So, I tried to use an interface. And then, I implemented the interface in every service class that used the IP address for HTTP calls. I assumed I could just change the IP address from the interface class.

This was not the case. So, I changed the IP address in every service class instead in order to make things work. 

So I ignored the interface and manually changed things. I believe this was an incorrect approach. But, I will figure it out. It had nothing to do with node-modules or base-href. It had something to do with my class not rendering the interface i cratd.

Comment: The solution in which I changed the ipaddress in every class (or file) worked. 


I haven't found the more feasible solution yet (because I haven't had to come across it yet (because in all honesty it seems like a deprecated problem)) but it still bothers me. I created a class or object that had a default IP address. I have assumed when I update the default address, it would have updated all other files with the correct IPaddress.

Comment: Basically every class that made a URL call to my server used XXX.XXX to make a call to my server. So I replaced XXX.XXX (which is the IPaddress) to myIP a class. So whenever I referenced myIP.address which is a string I would get that myIP.address="XXX.XXX". myIP was the interface and the address was the call from myIP. But I could not get it to work in Angular CLI.. so instead of just using a Singleton. I had to change every class that used XXX.XXX to PPP.XXX

Comment: This could have been more concise I think. But it all depends on your language, knowledge, and history. So.... it might be better if you posted a bit of history behind your problem. @Marcel

Comment: In the mean time I found my mistake as well.
My requirement was to read configuration from a piece of javascript given in the index.html's head section as javascript object.
Therefore I just used the window object and retrieved it. But I also wanted this unit tested so I added an optional parameter to the constructor providing a mock window object, causing this error.